# In Ruby on Rails unit testing update model against MySQL database gives error: ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have an ENUM type for a column I recently added to a previous table in the a MySQL database.

I'm unit testing creating a db entry with a valid ENUM value for that column.

The migration for adding the column is:

```
class AddStatusToMymodel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :my_model, :status,
               "ENUM('have_issues','no_issues', 'checking', 'error')"
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  enum status: %w[have_issues no_issues checking error].map { |i| [i.to_sym, i] }.to_h
end
```

Now, running a unit test that calls the controller method to create a record with `status: 'have_issues'` gives MySQL error:

```
ActiveRecord::ValueTooLong:
       Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'status' at row 1
```

But creating the model in rails console actually creates the entry in the database for that `'have_issues'` status.

On the other hand, when running the same test with `'checking'` status the entry is created in the test database.

What is the problem when using the test database with a valid ENUM type, and getting `ValueTooLong` error?

**UPDATE**:

As asked in comments I generate the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for dev and test databases and, in fact, they differ for the column `status`. For dev db it's ENUM, and for test db it's VARCHAR(8).

So, looks like the problem is when running the tests, and the statements to create the new column with type ENUM, the column is created with type VARCHAR. Is that a configuration to correctly create the column `status` with the type ENUM?

Comment: Can you please compare the output of `show create table` in both databases (dev and test)? If they differ, please show the `diff`.

Comment: I just updated the question with the `diff` @JaredBeck.

Comment: ".. for the column status .. dev db it's ENUM, .. test db it's VARCHAR(8)" Well, there's your problem :) What exact command(s) do you use to rebuild your test db from scratch? When you run those command(s) what is the output relevant to the `status` column, if any?

Comment: I guess I could solve this by destroying the test database, creating it again and running the tests.